# How can I get the row of a certain link in a table with data from a mysql database?

Tags: html, mysql, html-table

Here is my code:

```
<html>

<?php

DEFINE('DATABASE_USER', 'sfasdfasd');
DEFINE('DATABASE_PASSWORD', 'asdfasdfasdf');
DEFINE('DATABASE_HOST', 'sdfasdfasd');
DEFINE('DATABASE_NAME', 'dsafsdfasd');
$connect = mysql_connect(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD, DATABASE_NAME) or
die ("Hey loser, check your server connection.");
mysql_select_db("minedb");

$query = "SELECT * FROM ideastable ORDER BY datee DESC";

$quey1="select * from ideastable";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
?>
<table border=1 style="background-color:#000000;" >
<caption><EM>Ideas List</EM></caption>
<tr>
<th>IDEAS</th>
<th>Thumbs Ups</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['idea'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['thumbsup'];
$i = $row['id'];
echo $i;
echo '<a href="#" onClick="doSomething()">Thumbs Up!</a>';
echo "</td></tr>";

}
echo "</table>";

?>

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
function doSomething() {
var myVar = "<?php echo $i; ?>";    
alert(myVar);
$.load('uts.php?i=myVar');
    return false;
}
</SCRIPT>

</html>
```

My question is how would I be able to make it so that when I click the Thumbs Up it recognizes the row the link was in? I am making a site where you can rate some of the objects in a database and that is the start up of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about passing id to javascript function?

```
echo '<a href="#" onClick="doSomething('.$i.')">Thumbs Up!</a>';
```